# Factory method to create two kinds of cars based on an enum

Tags: c#, enum, factory-method

I am implementing the factory method approach. My intention is to know if my approach is correct for factory method. Any modifications to be done to align with the approach?

First  I am creating an interface IAuto.

```
 //IAuto.cs
    namespace TestDesignPatterns.Auto
    {
        public interface IAuto
        {

            void start();
            void stop();
        }
    }
```

Create a class that implements the IAuto.

```
    //clsBMW.cs
    namespace TestDesignPatterns.Auto
    {
        public class clsBMW : IAuto
        {
            public void start()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BMW started");
            }

            public void stop()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BMW stopped");
            }
        }
    }
```

Create another concrete class for Audi implementing IAuto.

```
namespace TestDesignPatterns.Auto
{
    public class clsAudi : IAuto
    {
        public void start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Audi started");
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Audi stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

Create an Interface of factory which creates the model.

```
//IautoFactory.cs
public interface IAutoFactory
    {
       IAuto createModel(ModelType m);
    }
```

concrete factory class.

```
//clsAutofactory.cs
 public class clsAutoFactory : IAutoFactory
    {
        public IAuto createModel(ModelType m)
        {
            IAuto instance = null;
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(m))
            {
                case 0:
                    instance = new clsBMW();
                    break;

                case 1:
                   instance =  new clsAudi();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;


            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Main Program

```
 public enum ModelType
    {
        BMW=0,
        Audi=1
    }
//program.cs

            IAutoFactory factory = new clsAutoFactory();
            IAuto model = factory.createModel(ModelType.Audi);
            model.start();
            model.stop();
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Does it work as intended? In that case, put forth the effort and post a real question. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) if you need help with that.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions WRT the capitalization of method names etc.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not name things with data type prefixes**

`clsAutoFactory`.  No.  Instead: `AutoFactory`

Names should be what they are in the problem domain - autos in this case. How a thing is implemented - is it an array? a class? an integer? etc. is not what's important, we can read code and the IDE is real smart. Writing code that is descriptive is the thing.

---

**Unnecessary interfaces**

There is no reason for any interfaces at this point. Just inherit from `Auto` class. Half the code goes away! Perhaps make it an abstract class and override methods as needed. I bet there is common code and/or default behavior.

In general `interface`s are for giving unrelated classes similar behavior. A `Parrot` might implement the `Idogable` so it can bark like a dog even though a `Parrot` is not a `Dog`. But a BMW is an Auto.

---

> I am implementing the factory method

You wrote a factory class not a factory method.

A factory method would be a method in some other class that does the factory thing. The code simple enough at this point that you could create a factory method - say a method in the `Auto` class; but I am not saying you should.

There are 3 "levels" of factory design which facilitates increasing construction complexity. i.e. factory method, factory (a simple class), and abstract factory for very complex things. The abstract factory may be appropriate if you were creating multiple auto makes with multiple models with multiple individual options; and perhaps different kinds like SUV, sports car, truck.

---

Ditto to [what @JAD said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205108/10221)

---

**`switch` default**

this is a perfect place for catching errors. If the `default` case is hit then obviously that model has not been implemented in your code. So capture that fact and let the user know.

---

Be more specific with auto instance names. `model` is too generic.

Not this:

```
IAuto model = factory.createModel(ModelType.Audi);
model.start();
model.stop();
```

but this:

```
IAuto myAudi = factory.createModel(ModelType.Audi);
myAudi.start();
myAudi.stop();
```

Comment: you mentioned "A factory method would be a method in some other class that does the factory thing". I am not clear on this.  My understanding was the method createModel is a method that creates the object.

Comment: made the code modifications as commented. Could you confirm if the approach is factory method and not factory class. I have added a method which returns the instance. Kindly correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You should not alter original question code. At worst it could make all the comments and answers moot. At best it gets confusing. Stack Exchange cannot be helpful to others if answers look wrong or nonsensical because code was altered later.

Comment: `public class clsAutoFactory`.  You said you wrote a "factory method" but  the factory is written as an independent class. Either way, it's a "factory" - i.e. it builds objects. There is a technical distinction between a factory method (not written as it's own class) and a factory (as its own class).

Answer (score 2):

`switch (Convert.ToInt32(m))` this is counterproductive and hurts readability. You can use `enums` in `switch` statements, so instead do this:

```
switch (m)
{
    case ModelType.BMW:
        bla
    case ModelType.Audi:
        bla
}
```